# return hello world without using any letters javascript

Tags: javascript

[This question](https://www.codewars.com/kata/oh-come-on-hello-world-once-again/train/javascript) is really bothering me!

My original solution looked like this:

```
function f(){
  return String.fromCharCode(72,101,108,108,111,44,32,119,111,114,108,100,33);
}
```

The error I am getting is `Your solution uses o letter`

My thought was that it was that there is an `o` in `fromCharCode` but then I [also tried generating `"Hello, world!"` here](http://www.jsfuck.com/) to guarantee no `o` is in the function, however, I saw the same error.

Can anyone spot anything silly I may be missing?

Comment: `function` keyword itself obviously contains `o` letter too

Comment: http://www.jsfuck.com/ will use no letters

Comment: ah got it! mixture of arrow function and `jsfuck.com`.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
f = () => '\x48\x65\x6C\x6C\x6F\x2C\x20\x77\x6F\x72\x6C\x64\x21';
```

> Time: 362ms Passed: 102 Failed: 0
>
> Test Results:
>
> - Test Passed: Value == 'Hello, world!'
>
>   - Banned letters check in your Solution
>   - Is there any letter from hello world?
>   - Completed in 2ms
> - Some random tests would be nice.
>
>   - Random Tests (100 of 100 Assertions)
>   - Completed in 22ms
>
> You have passed all of the tests! :)

Answer (score -1):

The Function is working fine.
Please find the working sample:
https://jsfiddle.net/L6qh89b1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script>
  function f(){
  return String.fromCharCode(72,101,108,108,111,44,32,119,111,114,108,100,33);
}

    document.write(f());
  </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you arent allowed use any letters from `hello, world!`. you are using an `o` in `function` and also is `fromCharCode()`